# In jQuery my function is not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to make two conditional statement with jQuery like this.

```js
$('#user_name, #user_email, #user_password').keyup(function () {
    if ($('#output-name').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#output-email').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#output-password').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#confirm-terms-of-use').is(':checked')
    ) {
        $('#register-button').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

$('#confirm-terms-of-use').change(function() {
    if ($('#output-name').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#output-email').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#output-password').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#confirm-terms-of-use').is(':checked')
    ) {
        $('#register-button').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

But you know this code is duplicated.

```js
if ($('#output-name').is('.field-output-comple') &&
    $('#output-email').is('.field-output-comple') &&
    $('#output-password').is('.field-output-comple') &&
    $('#confirm-terms-of-use').is(':checked')
) { 
    $('#register-button').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    $('#register-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

So I make this code with function like this.

```js
$('#user_name, #user_email, #user_password').keyup(isValidPassword())
$('#confirm-terms-of-use').change(isValidPassword())

function isValidPassword() {
    if ($('#output-name').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#output-email').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#output-password').is('.field-output-comple') &&
            $('#confirm-terms-of-use').is(':checked')
    ) {
        $('#register-button').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

But it does not worked well. No error but `isValidPassword` dose not output anything maybe. Where did I make mistake? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "not worked", specifically. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
.keyup(isValidPassword())
```

This doesn't pass the `isValidPassword` function itself to `keyup`, it *executes* the function and passes the *result* of that function.  And that function doesn't return anything, so its result is `undefined`.

Don't execute the function, just pass the function itself as a variable:

```
.keyup(isValidPassword)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the function reference to the event handlers, you are calling the function `isValidPassword` and is passing the value returned by it `undefined` as the event handler.

```
$('#user_name, #user_email, #user_password').keyup(isValidPassword)
$('#confirm-terms-of-use').change(isValidPassword)
```